# Scroll a future ListView

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm creating a page which has a list of items.  I want to scroll to the bottom of the page after the list has rendered.  The trouble is that I am using a FutureBuilder to fetch the list.  If I use `WidgetsBinding.addPostFrameCallback` this seems to get called before the `build()` method completes (maybe because it is still in the process of fetching data).

Is there a way to figure out that a Future has completed, the list has rendered and only then trigger the scroll to bottom?

```
@override
void initState() {

  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _postInit());

  super.initState();
}

Future<void> _postInit() async {
 _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder(
      future: _getList(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(child: SizedBox(height: 100, width: 100, child: new CircularProgressIndicator()));
            break;
          default:
            if(snapshot.hasError) {
              return Container();
            } else {
              return _buildListView(snapshot.data);
            }
          }
      }

    )
  );
}

Widget _buildListView(list) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: ListView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: list,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}
```

Comment: sure, add a simple code to reproduce the issue, so we can help you with your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _postInit());` from your `initState` method.

After that, add a `delayed` function inside your `_postInit()` method and call it when you receive the data to display your List, like this:

```
Future<void> _postInit() async {
   await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 100));
 _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: FutureBuilder(
      future: _getList(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        switch(snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.none:
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(child: SizedBox(height: 100, width: 100, child: new CircularProgressIndicator()));
            break;
          default:
            if(snapshot.hasError) {
              return Container();
            } else {
              _postInit();
              return _buildListView(snapshot.data);
            }
          }
      }

    )
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set reverse:true on the ListView and set the array you are iterating inside the ListView in reversed order.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).